# How to set environment variables and use them in IIS application in Azure 2.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, iis

Currently i want my log files to be dropped in particular location. Is there a way that i can get the Environment variable for my IIS application in Global.asax.cs

```
private string GetLoggingPath()
        {
            string rootFolder = string.Empty;
            var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/")).Parent;
            if (directoryInfo != null)
            {
                if (directoryInfo.Parent != null)
                {
                    rootFolder = directoryInfo.Parent.FullName;
                }
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rootFolder))
            {
                return Path.GetTempPath();
            }

            return Path.Combine(rootFolder, @"approot\bin\Data");
        }
```

I was looking into RoleRoot Environment variable but it is not available to me even when the application is running on Azure.

How can i set environment variables in azure so that i can use in my IIS application? What is the best way for me to get to the folder `E:\approot\bin\data` without hardcoding where `E:\` is the roleroot folder

Comment: Is there a reason you can't store this kind of information in your `web.config` file?

Comment: Nope. but sometimes the root folder changes from E:\ to F:\ and i have to write the logic to get the rootfolder. if it was for RoleRoot Environment  variable i would have got it easily by calling  Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RoleRoot")

Comment: Also i was thinking that i can use the cscfg file of the Azure Cloud service. But i was curious if Azure does support envionment variables or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't have a great way, it seems that environment variable is not set in the w3wp.exe process, but how about just using the following:

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(
    System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(
        System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath
    ),
    @"approot\bin\Data"
);
```

(pretty much the same as you, but without creating an DirectoryInfo).

Looking at the processes using Process Explorer I can see that only IISConfigurator.exe has the RoleRoot environment variable, so one option is you could use AppCmd.exe to set it in some configuration file during a startup task into a web.config or applicationHost.config and then read it from there.

But honestly I would just use the code above.

Comment: it would give the same path as HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/"). Wouldn't it?

Comment: Sorry, I probably did not understand the question, I thought you were just trying to read the folder from the web app of where your application was running and you didn't want to read that from the HttpContext. Could you clarify where are you trying to read that, is it like a startup task (aka which process?)

Comment: If you look at the method in the Question That gives me the following path : E:\approot\bin\data. WebRole is deployed at the following path E:\siteroot\0\ path. This is w3wp process and this code is executed in Global.asax.cs. Let me know if i answered your question

Comment: edited my answer now that I understand better, there does not seem to be a good way, and in fact no processes contain that in memory other than IISConfigurator.exe. Maybe using AppCmd set it into web.config in an app setting and read it after from there?

Comment: Thanks. This looks much more cleaner